# Left outer join in Hive causing reduction in rows

Tags: sql, join, hive

I'm using Hive to join tables using `left outer join` with the expectation that, since it is an outer join, the number of row in the left column should not reduce. However, that is not what I'm seeing.

Say table A has 100k rows and table B has 200k. My assumption is this, if I do a left outer join as such `select ... from A left outer join B on A.x=B.x`, I should never see rows fewer than 100k (A's size). In my case, I AM seeing a reduction in rows! I'm trying to see how I can replicate in a way that I can share on SO. In the mean time, if my assumption is wrong, please let me know.

There is one potential wrinkle in my query. There is an additional where clause as such:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM A 
LEFT outer join B on A.x=B.x 
WHERE (B.y is null or B.y is between date_sub(A.y,5) and date_sub(A.y,1)
```

Notice that I'm being careful about checking B.y for null value so it keeps left outer join semantics.

EDIT:
A couple of people have mentioned moving the where clause to the join. However, this causes problems. First it complains that 'or' isn't supported in join clause. If I remove that (since null check should no longer be required), I get this error:

`Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN`

This is probably because the `where` clause references table A as well as table B (it isn't static)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you not just move your `B.y is between date_sub(A.y,5) and date_sub(A.y,1)` clause onto the `JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `where` clause form your `join` and move it in `on`.

You can use the following query:

```
select ... 
from A 
left outer join B on A.x=B.x 
and (B.y is null or B.y is between date_sub(A.y,5) and date_sub(A.y,1)
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. First, it complains that the 'or' clause isn't supported in joins. When I remove that or (since moving it to join should remove the need to check for null), I get a new error: "Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN." I think the problem there is that conditions in join clause require static comparisons, not comparisons where both A.* and B.* are being used.

Comment: Moving where clause to the join on condition are not the same

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample query that shows that adding where clause in a left join is not the same as putting the same condition in the left join.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff32a/2

Therefore, your assumption that you will get same number of rows as table A is NOT CORRECT. You will get less rows due to filtering and there is nothing you can do to change this behavior.